# Using Spring Integration and AMQP, can I create Pub-Sub groups of Competing Consumers?

Tags: spring-integration, amqp, enterprise-integration

I'd like to create a setup like in the picture below:

[image]

Can this be done with Spring Integration's support for AMQP? I.e. can the communication channels in the picture be AMQP? The goal is so that:

1. Each component in the picture can be a separate server.
2. I can scale up each consumer group.
3. Only one worker from each consumer group processes the message.
4. Each consumer group receives each message.

I looked at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-channels), but am not sure if the two AMQP Message Channel implementations that SI provides (point-to-point and publish/subscribe) will do the trick here. In particular, would the point-to-point channel work like a regular Direct Channel, i.e. support multiple endpoints, only one of which receives each message?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the pub-sub channel with an outbound-channel-adapter that publishes to a `fanout` exchange.

Bind 2 queues to the fanout exchange; each will get a copy of the message.

Use inbound-channel-adapters for each of your consumers, each listening to the appropriate queue; the two groups of consumers will compete for their messages.